# Custom min operator for thrust::tuple in reduction

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

I'm trying to run a min reduction on a zip iterator, but using a custom operator to only take into consideration the second field from the tuple (the first field is a key, while the second field, the value, is actually relevant for the reduction)

However, I can't get it to work, and is currently computing a result that is present in the vector

The following code reproduces the problem:

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/zip_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/tuple.h>
#include <thrust/sequence.h>

typedef thrust::tuple<unsigned int, unsigned int> DereferencedIteratorTuple;

struct tuple_snd_min{
  __host__ __device__ 
  bool operator()(const DereferencedIteratorTuple& lhs,
                  const DereferencedIteratorTuple& rhs){
    return (thrust::get<1>(lhs) < thrust::get<1>(rhs));
  }
};


void f(){
    thrust::device_vector<unsigned int> X(10);
    thrust::device_vector<unsigned int> Y(10);

    thrust::sequence(X.begin(), X.end());
    thrust::sequence(Y.begin(), Y.end());

    X[0] = 5;
    Y[0] = 5;
    X[1] = 50;

    // X: 5 50 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
    // Y: 5 1  2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

    typedef thrust::device_vector<unsigned int>::iterator UIntIterator;
    typedef thrust::tuple<UIntIterator, UIntIterator> IteratorTuple;

    thrust::zip_iterator<IteratorTuple> first = 
        thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(X.begin(), Y.begin()));

    thrust::tuple<unsigned int, unsigned int> init = first[0];
    thrust::tuple<unsigned int, unsigned int> min = 
        thrust::reduce(first, first + 10, init, tuple_snd_min());

    printf("(%d,%d)\n", thrust::get<0>(min), thrust::get<1>(min));
    // should return (50,1)
    // returns (0,0)   
}
```

---

Thanks to Jared Hoberock's comment, I was able to fix this.

```
typedef thrust::tuple<unsigned int, unsigned int> DereferencedIteratorTuple;

struct tuple_snd_min{
  __host__ __device__ 
  const DereferencedIteratorTuple& operator()(const DereferencedIteratorTuple& lhs, const DereferencedIteratorTuple& rhs)
  {
    if(thrust::get<1>(lhs) < thrust::get<1>(rhs)) return lhs;
    else return rhs;
  }
};
```

Comment: Your `tuple_snd_min` functor doesn't return the min of the two, it returns `true` if the second element of `lhs` is less than the second element of `rhs`, and `false`, otherwise. I'm not sure why your code compiles; it seems like it shouldn't be able to. If you gave your `functor` to `thrust::min_element`, it ought to do what you want.

Comment: I did not realize that the functor should return the min of the two. It seems to me that this information is lacking in the documentation. Thanks to your comment I was able to fix the problem. If you want to put your comment into an answer I'm would be happy to mark it as accepted!

Answer (score 1):

This seems to have been caused by a misunderstanding about which operation the functor in `reduce` call must implement. As per the [documentation](http://thrust.github.io/doc/group__reductions.html#ga6869a1fbdf07499b2ed96fb3ec803c13), the functor must be a model of a *binary function*, whose output must be convertible to the input type. This is where your functor fails. Rather than this

```
struct tuple_snd_min{
  __host__ __device__ 
  bool operator()(const DereferencedIteratorTuple& lhs,
                  const DereferencedIteratorTuple& rhs){
    return (thrust::get<1>(lhs) < thrust::get<1>(rhs));
  }
};
```

your functor would need to be defined something like this:

```
struct tuple_snd_min{
  __host__ __device__ 
  int operator()(const DereferencedIteratorTuple& lhs,
                  const DereferencedIteratorTuple& rhs){
    return (thrust::get<1>(lhs) < thrust::get<1>(rhs)) ?
             thrust::get<1>(lhs) : thrust::get<1>(rhs);
  }
};
```

i.e. the function should return a value rather than act as a predicate.

[This answer was assembled from comments and posted as a community wiki entry to get this question off the unanswered queue]